# Running raw sql along with Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am using Eloquent for my new PHP project. But at some point I needed to run some raw sql queries. How can I set up eloquent so that I can run raw sql too ?

Comment: _How can I set up eloquent so that I can run raw sql too_ Don't know what kind of set up you're going for but you can check [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#retrieving-results) for calling raw queries

Comment: I mean I need to use Eloquent as well as some raw sql queries in some way.. thanks

Comment: Post some relevant code else its pretty Unclear.

Comment: See here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#running-queries

$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);

Answer (score 2):

```
User::select(DB::raw('name as full_name'))->get();
```

I have use DB::raw to setup the select query. There are many possible ways here. Make sure raw code does not break with ORM changes like changing table etc.